# Memory warning message

Tags: 7

I keep getting this error message:

> Warning: require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool. in Database::loadDriverFile() (line 1742 of /home/site/public_html/includes/database/database.inc).

I am not sure what the problem might be. It started when I installed Varnish 3.0; I couldn't get it to work, so I reverted back to my previous configuration with only APC. Now, I keep getting the message, and it is also visible to anonymous users. I have disabled the system help block from all themes, and turned off error reporting, but it still appears.

I also have mod-pagespeed enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to definitely be an APC issue, there's a [post about it on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p) which links through to a [bug report on PHP.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58982) for precisely this issue.

Comment: hey Clive: I might be being dense, but what is the prescribed solution for Linux boxes? Just to specify one of the mmap solutions above?

Comment: @acouch You're not being dense, I linked to that post as a whole but someone else edited these settings into my answer. According to the upvotes on the other answer (not the one that was accepted) in that question setting `apc.shm_size=x` and `apc.ttl=x` is what fixes the problem so kudos to you :)

Answer (score 3):

When we've had that same type of warning, increasing the APC memory limit has helped. Try adding

```
; APC Memory limit size
apc.shm_size=64
```

to the php.ini file and restarting apache. And obviously try increasing if that doesn't solve it.